# If statement to check whether a string has a capital letter, a lower case letter and a number

Tags: python

Can someone give an idea on how to test a string that:

- contains at least one upper case letter
- contains at least one lower case letter
- contains at least one number
- has a minimal length of 7 characters

Comment: look here: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html

Comment: have you tried any code ??

Comment: show a piece of code you have tried ?

Comment: upper=0
    lower=0
    password=0
    number=0
    while password <7:
        word=raw_input('Please enter a password: ')
        for ch in word:
            if ch.isupper():
                upper +=1
            if ch.islower():
                lower +=1
            if ch.isdigit():
                number +=1
            if len(word)>=7:
                password+=1
        if password!=7:
            print'Password needs to be a minimum of 7 characters'

Comment: this looks like a question for the OCR UK GCSE Computing examination...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
if (any(x.isupper() for x in s) and any(x.islower() for x in s) 
    and any(x.isdigit() for x in s) and len(s) >= 7):
```

Another way is to express your rules as a list of (lambda) functions

```
rules = [lambda s: any(x.isupper() for x in s), # must have at least one uppercase
        lambda s: any(x.islower() for x in s),  # must have at least one lowercase
        lambda s: any(x.isdigit() for x in s),  # must have at least one digit
        lambda s: len(s) >= 7                   # must be at least 7 characters
        ]

if all(rule(s) for rule in rules):
    ...
```

Regarding your comment. To build an error message

```
errors = []
if not any(x.isupper() for x in password):
    errors.append('Your password needs at least 1 capital.')
if not any(x.islower() for x in password):
    errors.append(...)
...

if errors:
    print " ".join(errors)
```

Comment: how would you modify it to give feed back as to which element isn't working.. for x in password if password !=(any(x.isupper(): print ' Your password needs at least 1 capital' ????

Comment: Better to separate each item into it's own `if not any(...):`

Comment: im getting an error message,'int' object is not iterable?

Comment: Is there any reason why you made a lambda rather than just doing `password.isupper() or password.islower()`?

Comment: @JohnRPerry, `password.isupper()` is `True` only if all letters are uppercase. We only need to ensure that there is at least one uppercase letter.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy right, but checking to see that `password.isupper() or password.islower()` is `False` will tell you whether it's a valid password (meaning it uses uppercase and lowercase letters) without having to write the lambda. The lambda is doing the same thing but with more code. It's obviously not a huge difference, I was just wondering if there was something I was missing.

Comment: @JohnRPerry, Oh I see. You mean to use `password.islower() == False` to check for an uppercase letter, etc? A similar trick is `password.lower() != password.upper()` to ensure there is some non-letter characters. Those tests are probably a little more efficient than a lambda/generator expression, but I don't think they convey their intention as clearly.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy ahh very good point!

Answer (score 10):

```
import re

s   = 'fooBar3'
rgx = re.compile(r'\d.*?[A-Z].*?[a-z]')

if rgx.match(''.join(sorted(s))) and len(s) >= 7:
    print 'ok'
```

Even more fun is this regex, which will report the type of character that is missing:

```
s = 'fooBar'

rules = [
    r'(?P<digit>\d)?',
    r'(?P<upper>[A-Z])?',
    r'(?P<lower>[a-z])?',
]

rgx      = re.compile(r'.*?'.join(rules))
checks   = rgx.match(''.join(sorted(s))).groupdict()
problems = [k for k,v in checks.iteritems() if v is None]

print checks   # {'upper': 'B', 'digit': None, 'lower': 'a'}
print problems # ['digit']
```

Finally, here's a variant of the excellent rules-based approach suggested by gnibbler.

```
s = 'fooBar'

rules = [
    lambda s: any(x.isupper() for x in s) or 'upper',
    lambda s: any(x.islower() for x in s) or 'lower',
    lambda s: any(x.isdigit() for x in s) or 'digit',
    lambda s: len(s) >= 7                 or 'length',
]

problems = [p for p in [r(s) for r in rules] if p != True]

print problems  # ['digit', 'length']
```

Comment: Sneaky way to apply a regex, but why why why?

Comment: @gnibbler OK, if you didn't like the first regex, you're gonna **LOVE** the second one. ;-)

Comment: Ended up precompiling all regexes and failing on the first that does not return `search(s)` match. That avoids sorting string as looking up "at least one symbol" fails since `#` and `_` will be in a different sort position