# Variable checking, something not right

Tags: python

I have spent some time searching the internet for sections this code to solve it, however once onto my code it doesn't seem to work. After the program comes to this bit, instead of showing the password strength it comes up with a blank space, no matter what I put in.

```
if EnteredPassword.isupper() or EnteredPassword.islower() or EnteredPassword.isdigit():
    print ("Your password is weak")
elif EnteredPassword.isupper()and EnteredPassword.islower():
    print ("Your password is medium")
elif EnteredPassword.isupper() and EnteredPassword.isdigit():
    print ("Your password is medium")
elif EnteredPassword.islower() and EnteredPassword.isdigit():
    print ("Your password is medium")
elif EnteredPassword.isupper() and EnteredPassword.islower() and EnteredPassword.isdigit():
    print ("Your password is strong")
```

I would appreciate it if anybody comes up with a solution to this problem as it is part of my schoolwork.

Comment: Sorry, what I am asking doesn't seem clear. I was just wondering if someone may come up with a solution as to why it comes up with a blank space, maybe because there is something wrong with the code I cannot see?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140408/if-statement-to-check-whether-a-string-has-a-capital-letter-a-lower-case-letter

Comment: IF this is the entire code, then none of your if statements are true, and because there is no `else` statement it won't print anything

Comment: The first one contains or and the last one contains and :)

Comment: When you do `EnteredPassword.isupper()and EnteredPassword.islower()` the password has to consist of only uppercase characters **AND** only lowercase characters *at the same time*. This can never be true. The same problem applies to the other comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

There is no else statement in your code. 
So in case it does not match any condition it will print nothing

```
if EnteredPassword.isupper() or EnteredPassword.islower() or EnteredPassword.isdigit():
    print ("Your password is weak")
elif EnteredPassword.isupper()and EnteredPassword.islower():
    print ("Your password is medium")
elif EnteredPassword.isupper() and EnteredPassword.isdigit():
    print ("Your password is medium")
elif EnteredPassword.islower() and EnteredPassword.isdigit():
    print ("Your password is medium")
elif EnteredPassword.isupper() and EnteredPassword.islower() and EnteredPassword.isdigit():
    print ("Your password is strong")
else
    print ("Write your message here")
```

Also you have used isupper,islower,isdigit in a wrong context.
These are used to check a complete string of that kind

```
Example :
ABHI- > isupper true
abhi -> islower true
099 -> isdigit true
```

But Abhi0 -> isupper, islower, isdigit all are false

I hope this clear your doubts.
For exact answer on how you should solve your problem of password check view answer on : 
[If statement to check whether a string has a capital letter, a lower case letter and a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140408/if-statement-to-check-whether-a-string-has-a-capital-letter-a-lower-case-letter)

Comment: Now it just goes straight for the else statement DX

Comment: because if password is of kind Abhi0 , this is not digit, not even upper and not a lower, so it end up in else

Comment: I see what you mean, so how can I make it so you can put upper, lower and digits?

Comment: Updated my answer, check and if that solves your problem, mark as correct to help the community